# Rails rendering vs re_direct with forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a test app that allows Users to create posts and then other users can comment on these posts. I'm now trying to create a way for users to message another user from post however I'm running into an issue with the forms. When User B wants to PM User A within User A's post I'd like to have the form for the message to have prefilled data. ie.

To: @user.username
From: @current_user.username

Since messages are their own Model and Controller I can't seem to re_direct a user and still keep that user specific information.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [acts as messageable gem](https://github.com/shannonwells/acts_as_messagable).

Comment: Checking this out, I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just have the form on the post's show form? And then pass the form values to your messages create action?

./app/controllers/message_controller.rb

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @message = Message.create(create_message_params) 
    @message.send
  end

  private 
  def create_message_params
    {}.tap do |h|
      h[:from_user_id] = params[:from_user_id]
      h[:to_user_id]   = params[:to_user_id]
      h[:text]         = params[:text]
    end
  end
end
```

./app/controllers/post_controller.rb

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @message = Message.new
  end
end
```

./app/views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<!-- omitting other post show html, showing just the message form -->
<% form_for(@message, url: messages_path do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:to_user_id, @post.author.id ) %>
  <%= text_area_tag(:text, @message.text) %>
  <br/>
  <%= f.submit("Send Message") %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit 2013.08.25 from the comments, the wish was for the messages to be in a different view**

First you'd have a link in the Post's "show" view:

```
<%= link_to "Send a message", new_messages_path(to_user_id: @post.author.id) %>
```

Then you'd have to create the new action, and a view, which takes in the incoming `to_user_id`, and stores it in a hidden field, perhaps. Then when they post to the `message_path` by submitting that messages form, you'd have the `to_user_id`, and the message, coupled with the current_user.id.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Really well thought out. However I really want it to be a separate page instead of it being on the post page.

Comment: That's a trivial change as I've now mentioned in my edit at the bottom of my answer. Make sense?

Comment: Dude, awesome! Believe it or not I tried the link_to method earlier but it wasn't working and now I see why. Thanks!